# How can i convert entity relations from corenlp to ontology?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, ontology

I want to create an ontology for news dataset. My task is to convert entity relations from corenlp to ontology.

I have extracted relations using Stanford corenlp.

```py
for k in range(0,50):
    text = df['event_summary'][k]
    print('sentence:'+text+ '\n')
    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie",
                            "outputFormat": "json",
                             "openie.triple.strict":"true",
                             "openie.max_entailments_per_clause":"1"})
    result = [output["sentences"][0]["openie"] for item in output]
    for i in result:
        for rel in i:
            relationSent=rel['subject'],rel['relation'],rel['object']
            print(relationSent )
            print('\n')
            df['Entity Relation'][k]= relationSent
```

My output looks like this:

```
sentence:U.S. fast-food restaurant chain Chick-fil-A warns that a security > breach may have leaked credit card details of 9

('security breach', 'leaked', 'credit card details of 9')


sentence:The Palestine Authority signs a treaty to join and participate in the International Criminal Court. (Wall Street Journal)

sentence:The Eurasian Economic Union between Russia

sentence:Vietnam’s new marriage law goes into effect

('Vietnam', 'has', 'new marriage law')
```

Now I want to convert these relations to ontology.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main questions you need to answer when building an ontology is "What inferences will you like from the ontology?". From the information you provided, I cannot answer that question. Hence the reason why it is not that easy to tell you how to build an ontology for the given sentences.

What seems more realistic to me is to place these sentences in an RDF triple store. Since RDF data is stored as `<subject, predicate, object>`, it matches the retrieved sentences very well. I.e., ('Vietnam', 'has', 'new marriage law') will become `<Vietnam, has, new_marriage_law>`. The advantage of doing this is that you can query the RDF data with SPARQL.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thing is I have extracted triples using corenlp now I need to convert these triples into RDF format. I am confused here how can I convert these triples to RDF in python?